# Why is accuracy droping in the last batch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using PyTorch for a classification task. For some reason, the accuracy drops in the last iteration, I would like to know why? any answer is appreciated.

Hers is the code

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):                          
    def __init__(self):                                    
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()             
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(89, 128),   
                                    nn.ReLU(),              
                                    nn.Linear(128, 64),      
                                    nn.ReLU(),              
                                    nn.Linear(64, 2))       
    def forward(self, x):               
        return self.layers(x)

def train(train_dl, model, epochs):  
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for (features, target) in train_dl:      
            optimizer.zero_grad() 
            features, target = features.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(features.float())
            target = target.view(-1) 
            loss = loss_function(output, target)
            loss.backward()  
            optimizer.step()
            output = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)
            correct = (output == target).float().sum()
            accuracy = correct / 512
            print(accuracy, loss)
        break
        
model = Classifier().to(device)
train(train_dl, model, 10)
```

and the last part of the output

```
tensor(0.6465, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6498, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6348, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6574, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6582, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6423, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6660, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6375, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6719, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6338, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6426, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6523, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6699, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6347, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6582, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6422, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6543, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6449, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6465, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6502, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6992, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6147, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6777, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6289, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6836, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6244, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.6738, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.6315, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(0.1387, device='cuda:0') tensor(0.5749, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because your last batch size is less than 512. It would be better to change this line

```py
accuracy = correct / 512
```

to:

```py
accuracy = correct / features.shape[0]
```

Alternatively, if you don't want your last batch to have a different size, you can drop it when you create the [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), by setting `drop_last=True`, something like this:

```py
train_dl = DataLoader(..., drop_last=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment but it's possible that it is just training instability. Does this always happen at the 10th epoch? Have you tried running it for longer than 10 epochs?